# Python Padding Oracle breaking script seems to be undefined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, encryption, padding-oracle-attack

I am tying to write a very simple script that will Just decrypt one byte of text
according to this formula `P′2[K] = Pn[K] ⊕ Cn-1[K] ⊕ C′[K]`
the oracle is a simple function that decrypt then check last byte to be equal to padding `0x15`. with p'2[k] is just 0x15(padding size)

```
def decrypt(cipher):
    dec = aes_context.decryptor()
    text = dec.update(cipher)
    if text[-1] == 0x15:
        return True, "Padding Match"
    else:
        return False, "No Match"
```

but the behavior seems Undefined . The loop is a simple loop from 0-> 255(number of tries to decrypt one block)

```
number = 0x01
index = 0
while index < 255:
    try_this_block = 0x0.to_bytes(7, "big") + number.to_bytes(1, "big")
    mod_ciphertext = try_this_block + c1
    state, error_text = decrypt(mod_ciphertext)
    if state:
        byte = try_this_block[-1] ^ 0x15 ^ c1[-1]
        text_back += byte.to_bytes(1, "big")
        break
    else:
        number += 1
    index += 1
```

The message That gets encrypted is just 8 bytes string + 8 bytes padding and gets decrypted with same key and IV each time. with c1, c2 correspond to ciphertext of m1, m2

```
m1 = b"khaled G"
m2 = 0x00.to_bytes(7, "big") + 0x015.to_bytes(1, "big")
```

WHOLE SOURCE CODE IS HERE:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import algorithms, modes, Cipher
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
import os

m1 = b"khaled G"
m2 = 0x00.to_bytes(7, "big") + 0x015.to_bytes(1, "big")

aes_context = Cipher(algorithms.AES(os.urandom(16)), modes.CBC(os.urandom(16)), default_backend())
enc = aes_context.encryptor()

c1 = enc.update(m1)
c2 = enc.update(m2)
c1, c2 = c2[0:8], c2[8:]

def decrypt(cipher):
    dec = aes_context.decryptor()
    text = dec.update(cipher)
    if text[-1] == 0x15:
        return True, "Padding Match"
    else:
        return False, "No Match"

text_back = b""
number = 0x01
index = 0
while index < 255:
    try_this_block = 0x0.to_bytes(7, "big") + number.to_bytes(1, "big")
    mod_ciphertext = try_this_block + c1
    state, error_text = decrypt(mod_ciphertext)
    if state:
        byte = try_this_block[-1] ^ 0x15 ^ c1[-1]
        text_back += byte.to_bytes(1, "big")
        break
    else:
        number += 1
    index += 1
print("text is {}".format(text_back))
```

Comment: You cannot have `0x15` if you have `8` byte data. The padding is in hex `0808080808080808`

Comment: @kelalaka You are Right if we are talking about a real world oracle This one is just a proof of concept of being able to decrypt one Byte Letter "G" in this Example . But I get different Result Each time I run this code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two problems in the code:

- First, AES is used to generate a ciphertext with a length of one block or 16 bytes. Then this one 16 bytes ciphertext block is split into two 8 bytes blocks, which are treated as 2 separate ciphertext blocks for the padding oracle attack. However, this is not allowed in the context of the relationship `P2 = C1 xor (C1' xor P2')` since the assumed relations between the two blocks do not exist, see e.g. [here](https://robertheaton.com/2013/07/29/padding-oracle-attack/). At this point I don't want to exclude the possibility that there is an algorithm for your case, but it will be a different one.
  The problem can be solved by using a block size equal to that of the algorithm. E.g. for a block size of 8 bytes TripleDES could be used. Alternatively, when using AES, a block size of 16 bytes must be used. In the former case, key and IV size have to be adjusted and furthermore the line `c1, c2 = c2[0:8], c2[8:]` is now obsolete:

  ```
  aes_context = Cipher(algorithms.TripleDES(os.urandom(24)), modes.CBC(os.urandom(8)), default_backend())
  ...
  c1 = enc.update(m1)
  c2 = enc.update(m2)
  #c1, c2 = c2[0:8], c2[8:]
  ...
  ```
- Secondly, the decryption does not take into account the IV. If the first block (`c1`) is to be decrypted, the preceding test block does not correspond to `c1` (as in the current code), but to `c0` and this is the IV. To solve the problem the following changes are necessary:

  ```
  iv = os.urandom(8)
  aes_context = Cipher(algorithms.TripleDES(os.urandom(24)), modes.CBC(iv), default_backend())
  ...
  c1 = enc.update(m1)
  c2 = enc.update(m2)
  #c1, c2 = c2[0:8], c2[8:]
  ...
  byte = try_this_block[-1] ^ 0x15 ^ iv[-1]
  ```

  With these changes the expected result (`G`) is obtained.

When using AES and a block size of 16 bytes, the data must additionally be modified accordingly.

- E.g. the following changes also provide the expected result (`G`):

  ```
  m1 = b"khaled Gkhaled G"
  m2 = 0x00.to_bytes(15, "big") + 0x015.to_bytes(1, "big")
  ...
  iv = os.urandom(16)
  aes_context = Cipher(algorithms.AES(os.urandom(16)), modes.CBC(iv), default_backend())
  ...
  c1 = enc.update(m1)
  c2 = enc.update(m2)
  #c1, c2 = c2[0:8], c2[8:]
  ...
  try_this_block = 0x0.to_bytes(15, "big") + number.to_bytes(1, "big")
  ...
  byte = try_this_block[-1] ^ 0x15 ^ iv[-1]
  ```

**Edit:**

- If algorithm/blocksize (AES, 16 bytes) and test data are *not* to be changed, then the test data will form only *one* plaintext block (composed of `m1` and `m2`) instead of two. In this case, `0x15` is returned as the result, since the padding byte is now the last byte of the block. With regard to the necessary code changes, it should be noted that when only one plaintext block is encrypted, only one ciphertext block is generated (`c1`):

  ```
  iv = os.urandom(16)                                                                     
  aes_context = Cipher(algorithms.AES(os.urandom(16)), modes.CBC(iv), default_backend())  
  ...
  c1 = enc.update(m1)  # empty
  c1 += enc.update(m2) # provides full block
  #c1, c2 = c2[0:8], c2[8:]
  ...
  try_this_block = 0x0.to_bytes(15, "big") + number.to_bytes(1, "big")
  ...
  byte = try_this_block[-1] ^ 0x15 ^ iv[-1]
  ```

  This returns as result `0x15`.

Comment: OHHH woww, Thank's alot those were Lots of errors :) . I Didn't notice at all That I was using the wrong block-size.although I think That problem Can just be solved By Xoring with the IV right ?.

Comment: @Khaled Gaber - I'm not sure how you want to compensate the inconsistent blocksizes with an XORing. But I might be missing something. Where exactly do you think an XORing should be placed to eliminate the different blocksizes?

Comment: ohh, imean i would not compensate, and just decrypt a padding byte(it's a proof )that's all . which would be ```0x15``` in this case. Right ?

Comment: OK, I think I understand. You want to continue using AES and your _unchanged_ test data. In this case you are right, the result would indeed be the padding byte, since it's the last byte of the block. However, plaintext and ciphertext now consist of only one block and not two. I have added this case with the necessary changes as third example in my answer, see the _Edit_ section.